# Mystery data point at [0,0] in d3.js scatterplot chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a scatterplot that's based off of [this](http://bl.ocks.org/nsonnad/4481531). All of my data looks good, but I have a single point at the coordinates (0,0). There is nothing in my dataset that matches this though. I'm using tooltips to show the values associated with the circle when you roll over them. This mystery point just has a blank tooltip meaning it has no values at all.

Any thoughts on what this might be and how I can figure out where it's coming from?

The data source for this chart is a CSV. I have no blank lines or empty cells in the data file.

Comment: have you checked for trailing comma's - just open the csv up in a text editor to check. When js parses a string of black space to a numbers with the + operator it comes up with 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you determining there is an extra data point? I ran your code and looked at the Javascript console. There are 46 data points which is correct.[image: Chrome Javascript console output]

Comment: The URL I gave wasn't actually my data, but looking at the console as you suggested told me I had a bunch of extra rows, so I was able to figure out that this was the issue. Thanks!